# JQuery Ajax model not opening in ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been trying for hours to get a modal to open up and show data from a GET Action method in a controller.

This is the jQuery function:

```
test = (url, id) => { 

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: {
                'id': id
            },
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                $("#formModal").find(".modal-body").html(res.Id);
                $("#formModal").find(".modal-title").html(res.Name);
                $("#formModal").modal('show');
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                alert("error");
            }
        })
    };
```

And this is the code my view which is calling the function:

```
<a asp-action="Index" 
   onclick="test('@Url.Action("GetStudies", "Studies", null, Context.Request.Scheme)', '@item.NodeId')">
   <i class="fa-solid fa-square-poll-horizontal" 
      style="color:darkolivegreen"></i>
</a>
```

The controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetStudies(int id)
{
    var results = (from t in _context.Studies
                   where !((from s in _context.Studies
                            join sn in _context.StudyNodes on s.Id equals sn.StudyId
                            where sn.NodeId == id
                            select s.Id).ToList()).Contains(t.Id)
                   select new Study
                          {
                              Id = t.Id,
                              Name = t.Name
                          }).ToList();

    return Ok(results);
}
```

I found in another post that I should be using return `ok(results)` and not `View()` but that didn't make any difference. The button in the view is taking me to the controller and the result query completes as it should but it looks like there is no response or at least no response is being passed back to the jQuery function.

What I am trying to do is display the results in a table in the modal so my guess is the results are in a form which the jQuery function doesn't recognize but I am new to this and need some guidance please.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your JQuery function can get your Url and id correctly.

If it doesn't work, you can try `function test(url,id) {}`.

Then replace the `a` tag with `button`:

```
<button asp-action="Index" type="button"
   onclick="test('@Url.Action("GetStudies", "Studies", null, Context.Request.Scheme)', '@item.NodeId')">
   <i class="fa-solid fa-square-poll-horizontal" 
      style="color:darkolivegreen"></i>
</button>
```

This works fine in my tests. You can have a try.

**Update:**

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div>
        <button asp-action="Index" type="button"
           onclick="test('@Url.Action("GetStudies", "Home", null, Context.Request.Scheme)', 1)">test
            <i class="fa-solid fa-square-poll-horizontal"
               style="color:darkolivegreen"></i>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div id="formModal" style="display:none;">
    </div>
    
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    test = (url, id) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: {
                'id': id
            },
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                var html = "";
                html += "<table class='table'><thread><tr><td>Id</td><td> Name </td></tr></thread><tbody>"
                for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
                    var id = res[i].id;
                    var name = res[i].name;
                    html += "<tr><td>"+ id +"</td><td>"+ name +"</td></tr>";
                }
                html += "</tbody></table>";
                $("#formModal").show();
                $("#formModal").html(html);

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                alert("error");
            }
        })
    };
</script>
```

When the button is clicked, the data is loaded into the table.

Is this the effect you want?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you didn't read the question properly.  The outward journey meaning the call to the Controller is working fine so the URL and id are being passed to the Controller.  I put a break point in the Controller to check.  The problem is the return journey i.e. AFTER the Controller it throws an error in the test function.

Comment: I used your code with no error thrown and no successful response executed. Of course, the controller is indeed called. When I change the `a` tag to a `button`, the result is printed out in the console. @A Cameron

Comment: Thanks @Chen.  Weirdly the button does open the modal having passed through the controller (unbelievable)  and I am getting the object passed to the console but I don't know how to access the object values in the modal.  I have tried a foreach loop in a table but the table is empty.

Comment: What does `access the object values in the modal` mean?  Do you wish to access the returned data from ajax? @A Cameron

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to show the data in a table but there is no obvious way to do this.  The ajax is returning something like res.Name but usually in MVC the Controller is passing an object which you can access through the @model reference and then loop through its properties to make a table.  So my question was and still is how to access the data which is being passed by the ajax function to the view?

Comment: Hi, @A Cameron, I updated my answer, you can have a try.

Comment: Thanks @Chen.  Not sure when I will have time.  Moved on to other things but I'll loop back when I have time.